# csv-import in redmine fails

Tags: csv, import, redmine

I am trying to transfer the data of an older redmine instance into a fresh one.
Because importing the sql-dump made the application crash, I now try to import the issues via csv-import.
But it doesn't work either. After selecting the csv-file redmine shows an error:

`Internal error An error occurred on the page you were trying to access. If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance. If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.`

No information is found in the logfile.
I varied encoding of the csv-file, but it seems to have nothing to do with the file itself.
Could the problem be related to incorrect permissions?
I have no idea where to search for the cause of the failing import function.
Maybe you have?

Thx

Bernie

Redmine version                5.0.5.stable

Ruby version                   3.1.4-p223 (2023-03-30) [x86_64-linux]

Rails version                  6.1.7.2

Environment                    production

Database adapter               Mysql2

Redmine plugins:
custom_users_as_assignees      0.0.4

OS: Debian 12 Bookworm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check production.log in redmine/log. And try to check permissions to all redmine folders. OS user you running redmine from must have permissions to these folders and files: `files log tmp public/plugin_assets config.ru`

To give access permissions in linux and macOS:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data files log tmp public/plugin_assets config.ru
chmod -R 755 files log tmp public/plugin_assets
```